# How can too much clawback tax on OAS benefits be withheld?

Tags: canada

[*Tax Planning for You and Your Family 2019*](https://home.kpmg/ca/en/home/insights/2018/11/tax-planning-for-you-and-your-family-2019.html) by KPMG. p 319.

> #### 20.3.2 Old Age Security benefits and the OAS clawback
>
> OAS benefits are a taxable pension available at age 65. Unlike CPP/QPP
>   payments, which are based on prior contributions, your entitlement to the
>   OAS benefit is based on your age and how long you have lived in Canada.
>   To receive the maximum pension, you must have lived in Canada for 40
>   years or more after turning 18. Partial pension may be available if you lived
>   in Canada for 10 or more years after turning 18. A social security agreement
>   between Canada and another country may allow you to add your period
>   of residence in the other country to your period of Canadian residence for
>   purposes of determining your OAS entitlement.
>
> OAS benefits are paid monthly and benefit rates are indexed quarterly for
>   inflation. At the time of writing, the maximum OAS payment is about $550
>   per month. For high-income taxpayers, these payments are completely

p 320.

> taxed
>   back through a special tax, known informally as the “clawback”. The tax
>   reduces benefits for taxpayers whose net income (after most deductions such
>   as RRSP contributions) is over $70,954. If your net income exceeds about
>   $114,640, the clawback will apply to 100% of your OAS benefits. Spouses’
>   incomes are not combined for purposes of the clawback; each taxpayer’s
>   income is considered separately.
>
> The clawback tax on OAS benefits is deducted from your monthly benefits
>   cheque. The amount withheld is based on your income in the prior two
>   years. For example, for the first six months of 2013, your tax withheld is
>   based on your 2011 income while your tax withheld for the last half of 2013
>   is based on your 2012 income. **If too much tax is withheld**, the excess will
>   be applied to reduce your income taxes otherwise owing or refunded to you
>   after you file your return for the year. If the tax withheld falls short of your
>   liability, you will have to repay the difference.

1. Who's incompetently withholding too much tax? Are authors hinting that Service Canada can be incompetent?
2. See title.

Comment: The quoted passages don't mention "incompetent". What makes you think incompetence is involved? From what I have heard of the US tax system (and less so of the Canadian one), while you don't want to _massively_ over-withhold, it seems safer to withhold slightly too much (and get a refund) than to under-withhold (and possibly get a fine). The very _opposite_ of incompetence...

Answer (score 1):

The clawback for 2013 is based on your 2013 income. Yet the withholding is based on your 2011 and 2012 income (over the course of the year.) If there is a dramatic change in income from year to year, too much or too little might be with-held -- not as a result of incompetence, but because 2011 and 2012 income didn't predict 2013 income. The paragraph you quoted explains that this will be fixed on your 2013 taxes.